# What kind of cable is this?

Tags: hdmi, cable

We found this cable in our server room at work but have no idea what it is. We know that one half of it is an HDMI but the other half just confuses us. Any ideas?

Plug: [image: Plug]

Socket: [image: Socket]

Comment: Does it happen to have any logos or signs on the side?

Comment: Closing - Not playing guessing games or identify this piece of thing

Answer (score 3):

It is most likely NOT HDMI at all, just uses the same connector.
That looks like a proprietary cable used by a KVM system or an out-of-band management system (which would make sense in a server-room). I have seen all sorts of weird cable-setups for these over the years.

Comment: Eh, if it's for KVM, then HDMI makes some sense. I was guessing the 2nd "not-quite-HDMI" port would be for stuff like keyboard or USB.

Comment: @grawity HDMI normallly doesn’t appear on servers at all. Vga is still the norm for servers as that is the easiest video output to get switched through a KVM. (Can be switched without using special controller chips.)

Comment: Well, the other weird port doesn't appear on servers either... So I assumed the cable was for interconnecting the KVM devices themselves. (E.g. server → short VGA/USB → KVM 1st half → long digital cable → KVM 2nd half → monitor/keyboard.) From the photos, it does look quite long.

Comment: Turns out it's an extension of some sort for a playstation VR system that someone dropped in there at some point.

Comment: @Lewimaron Hahaha.. We had started a guessing game here in the office (15 people) to see who would get closest to the real answer. Nobody got it right :-) Thanks for the update!